# How can I have hover effect on DIV's using the DIV ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a different hover effects on each div using the div id. Is it possible? I have been searching on google for a while now and all I see is hover effect using classname and tags. I want to do this using javascript or jquery. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: any effect will do for now. i can just edit it anyway. I have tried css but it affects every div.

Comment: @Joseph. I guess the _"Do it for me I don't have the time for it nor use google to find an answer"_ effect. There is an [excellent example](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) in the jQuery site for `hover` and css. Did you look there? **-1!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could evaluate the `id` from within the functions:

```
$(".hoverItems").hover( overState, outState );

function overState () {
  switch ( this.id ) {
    case "foo" :
      /* effect a */
      break;
    case "bar" :
      /* effect b */
  }
}

function outState () {
  switch ( this.id ) {
    case "foo" :
      /* undo effect a */
      break;
    case "bar" :
      /* undo effect b */
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/evikog/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can bind action to mouseEvent :
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

You just have to bind the event to your div and do your animation...

```
$("#foo,#bar").hover( overState, outState );

function overState () {
      /* effect */
}

function outState () {
      /* undo effect */
}
```

If you want to animate several div, gibe them a class. For example "animated":

HTML :

```
<div class="animated">blabla</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".animated").hover( overState, outState );
```

That way all your divs with the class animated will have the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css with the combination of class+id for specific style